# Why do I get errors with my App/Validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, customvalidator

I have been trying to validate that the first name does not include anything but letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores.

In my users.rb model I am using this code:

```
validates :first_namename, :firstname_convention => true
```

Which goes to the FirstNameConvention class:

```
class FirstnameConventionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, field, value)
    unless value.blank?
      record.errors[field] << "is not alphanumeric (letters, numbers,   underscores or periods)" unless value =~ /^[[:alnum:]._-]+$/
      record.errors[field] << "should start with a letter" unless value[0] =~ /[A-Za-z]/
      record.errors[field] << "contains illegal characters" unless    value.ascii_only?
    end
  end
end
```

And that file is stored in app/validators - a folder that I had to make.

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#index
Unknown validator: 'FirstnameConventionValidator'
```

I have tried placing:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{config.root}/app/validators"]
```

In config/application.rb:

```
 require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module ThorCinema
class Application < Rails::Application
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
# -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de

# Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true    
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'validators')
end

end
```

But this still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: app/validators will probably be not in the usual Rails-path. Try putting your folder into lib/validators, and see, if this works for you

Comment: So make the validators folder in there?

Comment: yes. this would be my suggestion

Comment: Where should I make the lib folder? In the default site directory?

Comment: The lib-folder should already exist (in the root-dir of you app)! Rails will look into this folder, if it cannot find classes etc.

Comment: I don't have a lib folder? I'm using rails 4.0.2 if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app/validators` is a good place to store validators, all you need to do, is to tell Rails about this folder existence. Add this line to your autoload paths in `config/application.rb` (`YourAppName::Application` section):

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'validators')
```

That's it

Comment: I've updated the question to show where I have put this but it still comes up with the same error. Is it because I made the validators folder in app rather than rails generating it?

Comment: @benjs.1 make sure you restarted server/console. No, there is no need to use generator. You can extend your application however you want.